# .OnAction with Parameters get executes two times in VBA Excel

Tags: vba, excel

```
Set menutext = contextmenu.Controls.add(Type:=msoControlPopup, before:=1)
With menutext
    '.name = "AddTechnologyColumn"
    .Caption = "Add Technology"
    .OnAction = "=addTechColumn(""" & TechGroupName & """)"
End With
```

'Module

```
Public Sub addTechColumn(TechGroupName As String)
    MsgBox TechGroupName
End Sub
```

But  addTechColumn() executes 2 times.

Comment: Can you give a minmal complete working example? https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Don't call a sub like a function. The parameters for a sub must not be enclosed in parentheses. Try: `.OnAction = "'addTechColumn """ & TechGroupName & """'"`. Note the whole string to call the sub is enclosed in single quotes.

Comment: @Axel Richter it worked for me. Thanks alot.

Comment: drop the use of `With menutext   .... End With`. it clutters up code ... use `menutext.Caption ...`  and    `menutext.OnAction ....`   .... use `With` if it simplifies a lot of lines, not just a couple.

Comment: @jsotola Thanks for suggestion.I'll try it.